# Unhandled exception - just in time debugging

Tags: arcobjects

I have an application (extension) that works fine on Windows XP platform. When I run this application on Windows 7 it throws this error. I am not sure what is causing this. I was thinking that it could be due to the fact that .net framework is not installed but I can see all in there. Looking for any ideas to resolve this issue.

Note: this error comes up when I click on a combox box. How can i get past this message box and get to actual error.

Thanks
Jay

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MapExt_Net.HEI_Extensions.layout.frmLayout.DisplaySize()
   at MapExt_Net.HEI_Extensions.layout.frmLayout.cBLayoutExtent_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised in `MapExt_Net.HEI_Extensions.layout.frmLayout.DisplaySize()` which seems to be implemented by yourself. Could you please paste the code of the method?